# Script won't add data to my variable

Tags: javascript

I use an ajax request to return an json encode.

Now the return data is as follows:

```
 {"24": {"24":["205", "22", "1", "1", "0", "0"]}};
```

Which im trying to add to :

```
///global set
var data = {"24":{"16":["172","22","1","1","0","0"],"15":["160","22","1","1","0","0"]}};
```

The problem is - my attempt is not adding to the variable. This is my script:

```
var result = {24: {24:[205, 22, 1, 1, 0, 0]}}; //return data test
var obj = {}
for ( var key in result ){              
if ( result.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
    // If the key already exists
    if ( data[ key ] === result[ key ] ) {

        // Empty the temporary object
        obj = {}
        // Loop through the subkeys
        for ( var subkey in result[ key ] ) {              
            if ( result[ key ].hasOwnProperty( [ subkey ] ) ) {

                // Fill in the temporary object
                obj[ subkey ] = result[ key ][ subkey ]
            }
        }

        // Add the new object to the original object
        data[ key ] = obj
    }

    // If the key doesn't exist, do it normally
    else {
        data[ key ] = result[ key ]
       }
    }
}
obj = null

//show change
 console.log(data);
```

I did a check on data after this code runs, and there is no new added data. Can any one see the mistake where / why its not inserting the data?

Comment: `data[ key ] === result[ key ]` <-- this line is wrong. That's saying, is the data at `data[key]` the same as `result[key]` - NOT "If the key already exists"

Comment: So what should i change it to ?

Comment: Other problems: `data` has string data, but `result` has integers, `.hasOwnProperty( [ subkey ] )` - why are you passing an array to `hasOwnProperty`? Not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve. What is the output supposed to look like?

Comment: http://www.paste.to/NDA3MzI1

Here is the desired result - im not sure why my ajax returns integers when i thought json_encode from PHP always returns strings.

Comment: @Hamish apologise for confusion i just checked - it does return in string data :) i edited the data on question to reflect that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data = {"24":{"16":["172","22","1","1","0","0"],"15":["160","22","1","1","0","0"]}};
var result = {"24": {"24":["205", "22", "1", "1", "0", "0"]}};

function forEach(o,cb){
    for(var i in o){
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(i)){
            cb(i);
        }
    }
}

forEach(result,function(key){
    if (!data[key]) data[key]={};
    forEach(result[key],function(subkey){
        if (!data[key][subkey]) data[key][subkey]=[];
        forEach(result[key][subkey],function(i){
            data[key][subkey].push(result[key][subkey][i]);
        });
    });
});

console.log(data);
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/363uy/

Comment: yes this works although it breaks if data is equal to nothing. Which is entirely possible by the way.. wonder how that can be solved?

Comment: @Dave you can easily fix that using something like `data=data||{};`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jyFB4/

Comment: @Dave: or maybe: `if ('undefined'!==typeof Object) data={};` this also works if `data` is not even defined. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/S2Yj8/

Comment: infact its not working now console.log is showing everything incorrectly.. see screenshots.

http://imgur.com/vNRlQ - second screenshot shows what "result" has - it is string data - http://imgur.com/sPRQT

Comment: @Dave: please post a jsFiddle, i can't tell what's wrong from seeing the screenshots. It does not happen in my demos.

Comment: I don't know why : http://jsfiddle.net/S2Yj8/6/ but it doesn't do it on this but it does on my main script.. so the only difference is the ajax part =/

Comment: http://imgur.com/YrDXr basically every single character in sdata becomes its own object, i don't know why it's doing it.

Comment: @Dave: did you decode the json-string - sent from the server - into an actual object? `var sdata=JSON.parse(data_from_ajax);` ?

Comment: http://www.paste.to/NDA3NTEw here is the ajax function that i didn't include + the php which created the json. var result is directly linking to that function so theres no parse involved =/

Comment: @Dave: after `sdata=sdata||{};` in http://imgur.com/H2V61 add this: `result=JSON.parse(result);`

Comment: just so i understand - how come i have to json parse - the console shows the data in the correct way in the response tab ?  :S

Comment: @Dave: the response tab detects that the sent string is in JSON-format and parses that automagically, although it is just a string ;)